# mysql function in query with dynamic sql involved

Tags: mysql, function, select

How to use a stored function instead of an explicitly written table name.
My query:

```
select "col_name" from get_table("col_name") where id = 2;
```

`get_table(col_name)` is my stored function which returns the table name after having processed column name.

I get error message

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("col_name") where id = 2' at line 1

I also tried to do like this:

```
DECLARE tableName varchar(30);
set tableName = get_table("col_name");
...
select "col_name" from tableName where id = 2;
```

This time I get error:

> no such a table - tableName

Comment: interesting question. I would shoot for a mysql prepared statement. Also depends what your outer programming language is, if you wanted to drive it that way

Comment: declare function, see this it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356694/mysql-function-call

Comment: To me the whole thing appears too much like a [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine). Your peers never seem to do it this way.

Comment: Drew - the select whitten above is a part of a different function with 3 arguments, so using the get_table("col_name") might help me to use only 2 arguments. Any way if i use the get_table("") or not I'd like to know what's wrong

Comment: sorry yellow, if you don't put the `@` sign in front of my name with no spaces I have no clue you are talking to me with alerts